# Will this simple JavaScript render anything in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.example.com/an-image.jpg";
```

I've created a new `<img>`, and assigned a source. Will this be added to the DOM? Or is it merely created in memory in the browser as a result of me running it?

Ultimately, I want to go on to get `img.width` and `img.height` which is why I'm doing this, so it's merely for image processing purposes, thus I want to avoid it appearing anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not be added to the DOM.

Comment: Succinct enough. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

there is `img.naturalWidth img.naturalHeight` properties which represents image natural dimensions loaded in it

Answer (score 0):

No it will not be added to the DOM. To add it to the DOM you can use appendchild method, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp
Example code:

```
document.getElementById("node").appendChild(img);
```